# Get minimum value from index in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this.

```
column1 column2

1         2
1         3
1         4
2         3
2         1
2         4
```

I would like to get minimum values for each value in column1. So my output would be

```
column1    column2
1             2
2             1
```

When I try the code

```
df = df[df['column2'].isin(df.groupby('column1').idxmin(['column2']).values)]
```

It gives me an empty dataframe and if I try

```
a = df[df['column2'].isin(df.groupby('column1').min()['column2'].values)]
```

it deletes some values, for reasons I don't understand.

I use python 2.7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Function [`DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.idxmax.html) return index values of minimal values of column `column2` per groups, so is necessary [`loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) for selecting:

```
df = df.loc[df.groupby('column1')['column2'].idxmin()]
print (df)
   column1  column2
0        1        2
4        2        1
```

Another solution is use [`sort_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_values.html) with [`drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
df = df.sort_values('column2', ascending=False).drop_duplicates('column1', keep='last')
```

EDIT:

If possible multiple minimal values and want select all of them use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
   column1  column2
0        1        2
1        1        3
2        1        4
3        2        1
4        2        1
5        2        4


df2 = df[df.groupby('column1')['column2'].transform('min') == df['column2']]
print (df2)
   column1  column2
0        1        2
3        2        1
4        2        1
```

Comment: life savior. Thanks so much Ill accept the answer as soon as possible. Cheers.